# Need a button that copies info from one div to another

Tags: javascript, html, button

I need a button that can take the information entered in the first div, and copy it into the second div when you press the button. However, I do not want any rows, just the information entered by the user. All help is appreciated.

Comment: can't help without current code

Comment: No, not hw, i am making a form for filling out orders

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: You need to try somethin and ask doubts if u struck with any problem.

Comment: Try something and post your code on **[http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/)** then ask for help on where you stuck on the code.

Comment: Asking Better Questions: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/

Comment: I apologize for the poorly worded question. I actually figured out after several hours, but thank you all for responding in a helpful way!

Comment: Please don't remove your entire question. Also, Please post your solution as an answer, so that it might help others.

Comment: I used the answer that i selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code will help you using just Javascript ;)

```
function copy()
{

    var fname = document.getElementById('FName').value;

    var lname = document.getElementById('LName').value;

    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = fname +", "+lname;

    return false;

}
```

The "results" is the id of the DIV where your result would be show ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just copy the info from one div into other div,use following code :

```
<div id = "a1" style="border:1px solid;float:left">Hello this is a dic</div>
<div id = "a2" style="border:1px solid;float:left;width:150px;height:50px;"></div>
<div style='clear:both'></div>
<input type='button' id = 'b1' name = 'click' value='Click'/>

jQuery('#b1').click(function(){
    var content = jQuery('#a1').text();
    jQuery('#a2').text(content);
});​
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SN3eU/).

Answer (score 0):

This will search all the input tags and append the value

**HTML**:

```
 <div id = "from"><input type="text" name="fName" id="fName"> .... <input ..... </div><br>
 <div id = "to"></div>
 <input type='button' value="click" onclick="copy()"/>
```

**JS**:

```
function copy() {
var allDataObject=document.getElementById('from').getElementsByTagName('input');
var inputCount=allDataObject.length;
var allData="";
for(var i=0;i<inputCount;i++) {
   allData + = allDataObject[i].value;
   allData + = "<br>";
}

document.getElementById('to').innerHTML=allData;
```